# How to read data from firebase?

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stored data in firebase realtime database like following:

```
{
   trivia: {
     "0": "long text",
     "1": "long text",
     "2": "long text",
   }
}
```

But when I exported the json from the database, it is rendered as an array like following:

```
{
   trivia: ["long text", "long text", "long text"]
}
```

What to do now? The following is my swift code and I'm getting this error - "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x106630b68) to 'NSString' (0x104b802a8)."

```
class TriviaViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var triviaList = [String]()   
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavBar()
        setupCollectionView()
        fetchTriviaFromFirebase()
    }

    func fetchTriviaFromFirebase() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref?.child("trivia").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (data) in
            self.triviaList.append(data.value as! String)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
    }


// Other functions - colectionview methds and other methods are below

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guard let value = data.value as? NSDictionary else { return }
guard let obj = value.allValues as? [String] else { return }
self.triviaList = obj
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. How to show "Loading text until the results show up?

Comment: can you try this " print(data.progress) " ?. I edited the answer . Now Its more securily

Comment: print(data.progress) is throwing this error -> Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'progress'

Comment: can you ask this with different question ? .